# mocking route path in react

Tags: reactjs, axios, jestjs, enzyme

I want to mock the route path e.g. [ http://localhost:3000/bookings/:bookingid ] for testing in app.test.js file. how can this be achieved?

Answer (score 0):

You can test the route by testing the content of the route function and mocking your own Request object.

Here's an example of how you could mock test a route:

**app.js**

```
router.post("/bookings/:bookingid", (req, res) => {

    // validate credentials
    const error = validateCredentials(req.body.username, req.body.password, req.params.bookingid);

    ...
}
```

**app.test.js**

```
describe("Booking routes", function() {
    const username = "John";
    const password = "stackoverflow";
    const bookingid = `123`;

    it("gets booking id", function() {
        expect(validateCredentials(username, password, bookingid)).to.be.undefined;
    });

});
```